# ASP.Net core - on form submit, refresh just a div and not the whole page

Tags: ajax, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

There are a lot of suggestions out there for this. But every answer I've seen hasn't really applied to .Net Core. I've been stuck for days so I'm hoping for help.

I have a very simple form - just two fields. When I submit, the controller returns to reload the page - `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));`.

I need it to just reload a div and not the whole Index page. I already have ajax in place to refresh the div on intervals. So, I need to figure out how to either return to just a div refresh and not a `return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));` - which I don't think is possible - or make it fire off that Ajax section on submit. I'm assuming Ajax the best option but I'm stumped.

Form:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreateBreak" class="DthdropdownGroup ml-3">
<div class="btn-group" style="margin-left:-1rem">
    <select class="form-group dropdownStyling btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block btn-outline-light" style="width: 7.4em;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmployeeId" asp-for="EmployeeId">
        <option>Dispatcher</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
        {
            <option class="dropdown-item pr-1 form-control" value="@item.Id">@item.DisplayName</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <select class="form-group dropdownStyling btn-sm dropdown-toggle d-inline-block btn-outline-light" style="width: 7.3em" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="EmpPosition" asp-for="EmpPosition">
        <option>Position</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Positions)
        {
            <option class="dropdown-item pr-1" value="@item.Id">@item.PositionName</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block dropdownStyling" id="break-submit" style="margin-left: -1rem; width:15rem;">Submit</button>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateBreak([Bind("Id,TimeEntered,TimeCleared,EmpSent,EmployeeId,EmpPosition,RlfPosition")] Break @break)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            @break.TimeEntered = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Add(@break);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(@break);
    }
```

Ajax set up that already works to refresh just the sections I need refreshed:

```
function RefreshDropDownsPartial() {
$.ajax({
    success: function () {
        $(" #DropDownsPartialDiv ").load(window.location.href + " #DropDownsPartialDiv ");
        $(" .audioAlert ").load(window.location.href + " .audioAlert ");
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Part of the index page that establishes the div I need reset on form submit:

```
<div class="listContent d-inline-block" id="DropDownsPartialDiv">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("../Shared/_Lists")
</div>
```

Break Model:

```
    namespace Seating.Models
{
    public partial class Break
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeEntered { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TimeCleared { get; set; }
        public bool? EmpSent { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int EmpPosition { get; set; }
        public int? RlfPosition { get; set; }

        public virtual Position EmpPositionNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual Position RlfPositionNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel that fills the dropdowns:

```
        public class ListsVM
    {
        public ListsVM()
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>();
            Positions = new List<Position>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<Dth> Dths { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Break> Breaks { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Lunch> Lunches { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int EmpPosition { get; set; }
        public bool EmpSent { get; set; }
        public bool LunchTime { get; set; }
        public bool LongerLunch { get; set; }
        public bool DblLunch { get; set; }
    }
```

The /Shared/_Lists just returns tables that go above the form. I can post that code but it's  working well. I just need to refresh those tables on submit. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: `I need it to just reload a div and not the whole Index page`What about using a [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?Put the div code  into a partial view,and refresh the partial view with ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path with using ajax, follow steps below;

1. Use controller action below; we're now returning json, and binding only 2 parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> CreateBreak(int EmployeeId, int EmpPosition)
{
   Break newBreak = new Break();

   newBreak.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
   newBreak.EmpPosition = EmpPosition;
   newBreak.TimeEntered = DateTime.Now;
      
   _context.Add(newBreak);
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

   return Json(newBreak);
}
```

2. Add an id to your form, I used `ajax_submit`.

```
<form id="ajax_submit" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CreateBreak" class="DthdropdownGroup ml-3">
...
</form>
```

3. Add this new script, this will send the values to the controller action above. Once successful, it will refresh that part of the div.

```
@section scripts {
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         // bind event to your form
         $("#ajax_submit").submit(function(e){

            // prevent regular form submit
            e.preventDefault();
  
            var data = {
               'EmployeeId' : $("#EmployeeId").val(),
               'EmpPosition' : $("#EmpPosition").val()
            }       
  
            $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("CreateBreak","Home")',
               type: 'POST',
               data: data,
               success: function(result){
                  console.log(result);
                   
                  // refresh
                  $(" #DropDownsPartialDiv ").load(window.location.href + " #DropDownsPartialDiv ");
                  $(" .audioAlert ").load(window.location.href + " .audioAlert ");
               },
               error: function (err){
                  console.log(err);
               }
            });
         })
      });
   </script>
}
```

---

3A. Check your layout;
Jquery should be before the RenderSection scripts

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

You could also try `$(document).on("submit","#ajax_submit", function(e)`

```
@section scripts {
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         // bind event to your form
         $(document).on("submit","#ajax_submit", function(e){
         // prevent regular form submit
            e.preventDefault();
  
            var data = {
               'EmployeeId' : $("#EmployeeId").val(),
               'EmpPosition' : $("#EmpPosition").val()
            };      
  
            $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("CreateBreak","Home")',
               type: 'POST',
               data: data,
               success: function(result){
                  console.log(result);
                   
                  // refresh
                  $(" #DropDownsPartialDiv ").load(window.location.href + " #DropDownsPartialDiv ");
                  $(" .audioAlert ").load(window.location.href + " .audioAlert ");
               },
               error: function (err){
                  console.log(err);
               }
            });
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242942/discussion-on-answer-by-jerdine-sabio-asp-net-core-on-form-submit-refresh-jus).